# How to create a file (placeholder?) with nonzero (>1k) size but 0 size on disk, on windows?

Tags: ntfs, size

Just like a file that is "online-only" in dropbox, which shows its original size in the ntfs system, at the same time 0 bytes on disk?

I am aware that if the file size is smaller than 1k then it is the default behaviour. I am curious how cloud syncing apps do it. I searched but haven't found any relevant answers.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I would assume low-level access to the filesystem to update the index (File allocation Table, but whatever its called for NTFS)

Comment: What you are after is known as a "sparce file", the duplicate should have a few pointers.